# Reversing a key-gen firmware for RISC-V

Tags: binary-analysis, firmware, hardware, deobfuscation, embedded

I would like to study this firmware for [Sipeed MAix](https://www.seeedstudio.com/sipeed), a RISC-V development board. You can download it here: [`key_gen_v1.2.zip`](https://bbs.sipeed.com/uploads/default/original/1X/bca0832bed92a1ada63bd05327688784e2ef14d1.zip). As the name suggests, its purpose is to

1. calculate and print a "machine key" to the serial port,
2. close JTAG port forever, and
3. write one-off AES key.

The machine key is required when downloading [other demo firmware](https://www.maixhub.com/), reversing which is NOT the primary target of this post. For more context, see [this thread](https://bbs.sipeed.com/t/topic/845). The point of the reversing is to figure out how to get the machine key without disabling JTAG permanently.

A quick analysis by `binwalk` yields nothing interesting.

```
$ binwalk -e key_gen_v1.2.bin

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Entropy analysis suggests that the firmware uses no obfuscation

[image]

Here is the output of `strings`

```
sP00sP 0sP@0sP@4
&#41'#0A'#<Q%#8a%#4q%#0
$#8A##4Q##0a##8
"#0!##<1!#8A!#<
$#8A##4Q##0a##8
                0000000000000000
0123456789abcdef
0123456789ABCDEF
                0000000000000000
                0000000000000000C
                0000000000000000
         (((((
V (%lu) %s: misaligned load recovered at %08lx. len:%02d,addr:%08lx,reg:%02d,data:%016lx,signed:%1d,float:%1d
V (%lu) %s: misaligned store recovered at %08lx. len:%02d,addr:%08lx,reg:%02d,data:%016lx,float:%1d
[0;31mE (%lu) %s: Out of memory
[0;33mW (%lu) %s: sys_exit called by core %ld with 0x%lx
[0;31mE (%lu) %s: Unsupported syscall %ld: a0=%lx, a1=%lx, a2=%lx!
?Error:  No workable settings found.
Error:  No appropriate ratio found.
```

In [Reversing the WRT120N’s Firmware Obfuscation](http://www.devttys0.com/2014/02/reversing-the-wrt120n-firmware-obfuscation/), the breakthrough was made by observing the output on the serial port. However, this particular firmware doesn't output much useful information to the serial port. In addition, I have yet find a decent disassembler for RISC-V (like IDA for ARM).

What can I do next?

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra

As of early December Ghidra has RISC-V support in master.  It should be added to the 9.2 release, until then you would have to build from source.